# Compare dates with bash

Tags: bash, unix

I need to collect user input to determine date and then compare that with today's date.

Here is what I have:

```
echo "Enter Current Date (YYMMDD):"
read date
current_date= date +"%y%m%d"
if [ "$date" == "$current_date" ]; then
        echo "match"
   else
        echo "no match"
fi
```

It prints no match for when it is expected to be a match and no match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "Enter Current Date (YYMMDD):"
read date
current_date=`date +"%y%m%d"`

if [ "$date" = "$current_date" ]; then
        echo "match"
   else
        echo "no match"
fi
```

Change is on this line :

```
current_date=`date +"%y%m%d"`
```

Reason:  In your code, you are using `current_date= date +"%y%m%d"`. Though your intention was to use the date command to generate the current date, this line behaves differently (becomes equivalent to current_date= ; date +"%y%m%d"; and results in current_date being empty. You can `echo $current_date` to verify this. With the correction provided, we are executing the date command and saving the output to current_date variable. Hope it is clear now. I don't know how to explain in a better way... :-)

Comment: You may want to explain why it works now, and what was the mistake.